# Latex IEEETran cls use titlesec package

Tags: titlesec

How do I  use the `titlesec` package if I am under `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` ?

I got the following error:

```
  ！Undefined control sequence.

  <argument> \subparagraph
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `titlesec` package assumes all of the section levels provided by the standard classes are present.  This includes the `subparagraph` level.  The `IEEEtrans` class doesn't define a level `subparagraph` so `titlesec` doesn't know what to do when it tries to redefine it.  The simple solution is to simply add the line

```
\newcommand{\subparagraph}{}
```

to your preamble before loading the `titlesec` package.  If you need to actually have it work, you will then need to provide its definition via the regular `titlesec` methods.

Comment: I was using `sig-alternate.cls` from ACM. This solves my pain.

Comment: Same problem and solution for the Springer svjour3 class